# SQL Server stored procedure returning 'fail'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that needs to delete a few rows of data. But when I run it, it returns a fail and a value of -6.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[p_CaseFiles_Exhibits_DeleteExhibits]
  @ExhibitID int
, @Message nvarchar(50) output
as
declare @FileID int
set @FileID = (select FileID from CaseFileExhibits where ExhibitID = @ExhibitID)
begin transaction
  begin try
    delete from CaseFileExhibitMovementTracking where ExhibitID = @ExhibitID
    delete from CaseFileExhibitAttachments where CaseFileExhibitID = @ExhibitID
    delete from CaseFileExhibits where ExhibitID = @ExhibitID
    delete from CaseFileExhibitPropertyLink where ExhibitID = @ExhibitID
    update CaseFileQuickStats set ExhibitCount = ExhibitCount -1 where CaseFileID = @FileID    
    commit transaction
  end try
  begin catch
    set @Message='Fail'
    rollback transaction
  end catch
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong.

Comment: did you attempt running the stored proc with each query individually to see which query might be failing? Or even running each one separately outside of the stored proc?

Comment: You should use the **TAGS** for this kind of "meta" information - I updated it for you now

Comment: Do you have any foreign keys/primary keys/unique constraints?

Comment: -6 means a severity 16 error.

Comment: mmm Seems a bit tedious(second option) I've tried debugging it in Server 2008 but I won't let me. Looking currently to see if there is anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're able to check out the messages yourself, add this to your CATCH block:

```
SELECT
ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

You may want to change that SELECT to PRINT, and then you'll be able to see the results in the 'Messages' tab when running the SP within SSMS.

I suspect it's a problem with a Foreign Key or a possible trigger.

Comment: Yes Thank you very much. I knew there was a foreign key constraint on the CaseFileExhibitLinkProperty, and since I have it after it is conflicting it doesn't work. I just put " delete from CaseFileExhibitPropertyLink where ExhibitID = @ExhibitID" as the first delete then it doesn't violate the constraint and it works.